# How to plot Pandas .groupby() objects in Seaborn - using method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I would be really grateful for any advice on how to pipe a Pandas .groupby() object into Seaborn

Im trying to plot the .groupby() object but it give me an error message:
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

```
gapminder.\
    groupby('year').\
    agg({'pop' : ['sum'],
         'lifeExp' : ['mean']}).\
    reset_index().\
    pipe((sns.relplot, "data"), x = "pop", y = "lifeExp", kind = "scatter").\
    set(xscale = "log")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a lambda, then you can call the function as you please:

```
.pipe(lambda d: sns.relplot(data=d, x="pop", y="lifeExp", kind="scatter"))
```

Where `d` represents your DataFrame, passed in whole as the sole argument to `.pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is helped by a new feature added to Pandas in version 0.25, "Named aggregation with .groupby()". This allows for the creation of variables through the .agg() function and the output into a tidy dataframe with a uniform index, as opposed to the multi-indexed groupby object in Pandas <= version 0.24.
Below shows how a query can be chained through Pandas and also seamlessly into Seaborn.

```
gapminder.\
   groupby('year').\
   agg(pop_sum = ('pop', sum), 
       lifeExp_mean = ('lifeExp', 'mean')).\
   reset_index().\
   pipe((sns.relplot,"data"), x="pop_sum", y="lifeExp_mean", kind="scatter").\
   set(xscale = "log")
plt.show()
```

Comment: The `(sns.relplot,"data")` part does not seem like it would work. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does would you believe. The big discovery for me was the named aggregation for Pandas recent update - use that and then reset_index so it identifies the variable label and then pipe through the seaborn code. I try to use Seaborn as such as like GGplot2 so I only use catplot or relplot - then specify the 'kind'. But works great